# Android - How to set margins programmatically in gridlayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-gridlayout

Trying to get a few rows of buttons in a grid layout.

The buttons size ok, but the margins seems broken.

```
package ray.gui;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        int size=150;
        int rows=2;
        int columns=5;
        Integer[] colors=new Integer[columns];
        colors[0]=Color.RED;
        colors[1]=Color.YELLOW;
        colors[2]=Color.GREEN;
        colors[3]=Color.BLUE;
        colors[4]=Color.rgb(255,165,0);
        GridLayout gridLayout=new GridLayout(this);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(rows);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(columns);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100);
        gridLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        for(int i=0;i<rows*columns;i++) {
            Button button=new Button(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size,size);
            params.width = size;
            params.height= size;
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
            button.setText(""+i);
            //button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            if(i/columns%2==1)
                button.setBackgroundColor(colors[i%columns]);
            gridLayout.addView(button);
        }
        setContentView(gridLayout);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

edit: the code below worked.

```
    Button button=new Button(this);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(size*20/100,size*20/100,size*20/100,size*20/100);
    layoutParams.width=size;
    layoutParams.height=size;
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: What margins are you talking about?  Internal margins between cells or the outer margins around the entire view?  It might help if you share a screenshot of what you're seeing and what you'd like to see.

Comment: GridLayout: layoutParams.setMargins(size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100);

Comment: layoutParams.setMargins(size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100);

Comment: I see the code, but it's not clear what you are trying to achieve so it's not clear what the problem is.  Are you trying to specify the margin around cells in the grid, or the margin around the entire grid view?

Comment: i wanted some extra space between the rows and columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A view's layoutParams is for its parent to use, not itself. So a gridLayout's layoutParams shouldn't be a GridLayout.LayoutParams because its parent is not a GridLayout.

Try replacing

```
    GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100,size*30/100);
```

with

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout
            .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = 45;
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 45;
    layoutParams.topMargin = 45;
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 45;
```

Comment: doc at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html says: Class Overview

Layout information associated with each of the children of a GridLayout.

Comment: Yes, which means you should use GridLayout.LayoutParams on each cell of a GridLayout, not on the GridLayout itself. What kind of LayoutParams you use on the GridLayout depends on what its parent view is.